# How can I get an array of youtube video names from an array of youtube video links?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, youtube, discord.js

I'm making a discord music bot (I've said this so many times in these questions) and I'm working specifically on the queue command, the only problem I've hit so far is getting an array of youtube names from the array of youtube links I already have from the music queue. The best I could've come up with to display something like a queue is like this

```
var server = servers[message.guild.id];
console.log('QUEUE:')

if(server === undefined || !server.queue[i]){
    message.channel.send("No songs in the queue");
    return;
}
for(let i = 0; i < server.queue.length; i++) {
    YTDL.getInfo(server.queue[i], function(err,info) {
        message.channel.send(info.title)
        console.log(info.title)
    })
}
```

The only problem with this is that it can be interrupted while sending the queue, and it just doesn't look good. If any of you can help me out it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped out by someone on "The Coding Den" discord server. The solution he told me about was async and await.

````
var server = servers[message.guild.id];

var queueTitles = []
function queueCheck(queueSpot) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        YTDL.getInfo(server.queue[queueSpot], (err, info) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(info);
        });
    });
}
async function queueWait(queueWaitSpot) {
    let info = await queueCheck(queueWaitSpot);
    queueTitles.push(info.title)
}
console.log('QUEUE:')
if(server === undefined) {
    console.log("No songs in the queue");
    messagesend("No songs in the queue");
    return;
}
for(let i = 0; i < server.queue.length; i++) {
        await queueWait(i)
}
if(queueTitles.length === 0) {
    console.log("No songs in the queue")
    messagesend("No songs in the queue");
    return;
}
console.log("```\n" + queueTitles.join('\n') + "\n```");
message.channel.send(queueTitles.join('\n'));
````